# partial derivative w.r.t. (lnS)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am not able to understand this from a book about finance probabilities:

Given that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-q)S\frac{\partial f}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2} = rf $$

We now define:

$$Z = \ln S$$

So that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Z^2} = rf $$

How is the second equation derived?

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Just apply the variable change and the chain rule.

Comment: @jlandercy, can you help me with more details, like step-by-step process?

Comment: Recall that, in general, $da/db = (da/dc)(dc/db)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.e., $S=e^Z$ or $\partial S=e^Z\partial Z=S\partial Z$, we have:

(1) $S\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}=S\frac{\partial f}{e^Z\partial Z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z}$

Now for the second derivative, we have:

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Z^2}=S\frac{\partial(S\frac{\partial f}{\partial S})}{\partial S}=S\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}+S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z}+S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2}$

Also, the right term can be written as:

(2) $S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Z^2}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z}$

Now, substitute (1) and (2) into your first equation:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-q)S\frac{\partial f}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2}$

$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-q)\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Z^2}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z})$

$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Z^2}$

Comment: Farshid Farhat, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer if it seems OK to you.